# Using the qiskit_textbook Package

Tags: qiskit

I've installed the qiskit_textbook package in Anaconda on Windows 10 using
`pip install git+https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook.git#subdirectory=qiskit-textbook-src`
from the instructions at https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-prerequisites/setting-the-environment.html .

But I don't see any jupyter notebooks to open. How do you begin working with the qiskit tutorial notebooks? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: I believe that package is specifically used for widgets and tools that will be called upon when going through the textbook. I do not think it includes the jupyter notebooks themselves. I think you follow the code they have pasted throughout the chapters within your own jupyter notebook.

Comment: Recently received a fairly complete answer at https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14096/using-the-qiskit-textbook-package/14123#14123